# Merging elements of a specific value with its neighbouring element in a list

Tags: python, list, element

I'm trying to combine certain elements in a list if they are of a specific value with its righter-neighbouring element. 
(The specific value in this case being a minus sign).
Say I have the following list:

```
x = ['0', '0', '8', '-', '6', '4', '0', '5', '1', '2', '1', '2', '-', '5']
```

What can I do to the list so that It'll look like this?:

```
x = ['0', '0', '8', '-6', '4', '0', '5', '1', '2', '1', '2', '-5']
```

I basically need every instance of the element '-' to be paired with the next element (of which the index is +1 of the index of the minus sign).
Sorry if this is quite vague, I'm still quite new to python and as such my terminology may be lacking.

Answer (score 1):

```
neg = False
out = []
for i in x:
    if i == '-':
        neg = True
    else:
        if neg:
            out += ['-' + i]
            neg = False
        else:
            out += [i]


In [18]: out
Out[18]: ['0', '0', '8', '-6', '4', '0', '5', '1', '2', '1', '2', '-5']
```

In the code above, there is flag `neg` which indicates previous item was a minus sign or not (True means it was a minus sign). Then we populate the `out` list with the element from x with the rule that if you have `-` then set the flag to `True` but do nothing. Then if the element is not `-` and `neg` is `True` then append negative of the element and set the flag to `False`, but if the flag is `False` just append the element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x = ['0', '0', '8', '-', '6', '4', '0', '5', '1', '2', '1', '2', '-', '5']

for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] == '-':
        x[i+1] = x[i] + x[i+1]

y = [i for i in x if i != '-']
print(y)
```

It merges elements, then remove all of minus sign`'-'` from list.